# Calculating normals for a polygon mesh (3D computer graphics)

Tags: computer-science, 3d

I want to write a program to generate arches, a common architectural form, and export them to a wavefront object format for sharing with various three dimensional graphics editors. To do this, I need to generate normals for inclusion in the wavefront object. I understand that normals represent the orientation of a surface at a vertex. I need to understand how to calculate them, and specifically what the i,j,k coordinates signify.

Comment: You may want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product.  Although, calculating the normal from your mesh is going to make your shading look not as smooth compared to calculating your normal from the actual equation of the thing you are approximating.  This course https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291 also has more info.

Comment: Face normals are easy to compute, per Omnomnomnom's answer. *Vertex* normals can then be obtained through a weighted average of the face normals; see e.g. [Max's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10867651.1999.10487501).

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a polygon mesh, presumably you'll want normal vector given a particular triangular face.

First of all, definitions: a [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) on some point of a surface is a [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) that points perpendicular to that surface at that point.  Since each surface (locally) has two sides, you have two valid directions of normal-vectors: one side on which the vector would point towards the surface, and one side on which the vector would point away from the surface.

Now, suppose you have a triangle determined by the three points $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3), b = (b_1,b_2,b_3),$ and $c = (c_1,c_2,c_3)$.  Define 
$$
v_{ab}=(b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2,b_3-a_3)\\
v_{bc}=(c_1-b_1,c_2-b_2,c_3-b_3)
$$
In order to find a normal vector, calculate $v_{ab}\times v_{bc}$ or, for the opposite orientation, $v_{bc} \times v_{ab}$, where "$\times$" here denotes the [cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: Let me know if I can explain anything above more thoroughly

Comment: how would you create (approx) a sphere? considering that the minimum surface unit given is a triangle? in other words, how would you triangular mesh a sphere? (here the sphere is taken as an example for any object)

Comment: @Anonymous you should post a new question about that.

Comment: I think I got it, $A_i = r(\theta_i, \phi_i) \; B_i = r(\theta_i, \phi_i +\Delta\phi) \; C_i = r(\theta_i +\Delta\theta, \phi_i)$ where $\vec{r}=(\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi)$ and then iterate $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$ as $\theta_i = \theta_{i-1}+\Delta\theta$

Comment: so in general, parametrize the surface with 2 variables, and to triangular mesh vary each variable.

Comment: so for the question $\vec{n}_i = \vec{AB}_i\times\vec{AC}_i$

Comment: I think however, for implementation details one need to also consider a point $A_i'$ given by $A_i+\vec{AC}_i+\vec{AB}_i$ otherwise the object wouldnt be complete, and the normal would be computed in the other sense (clockwise)

Comment: @Anonymous okay, sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Accumulating the Cross-product of component triangles is one way. Glassner
notes that the cross of the diagonals of a quad gives the same answer.  Coons
pointed out that the vector of the areas of the polygons projected onto the coordinate planes also gives the same answer.  I use a trapezoid accumulation
to do this calculation from civil engineering.  I find this mathematically unsatisfying and at odds with
the idea that, as an element shrinks in size, its importance increases.  I therefore rescale each edge around a vertex by the inverse square of its length before this accumulation.  It lights smooth surfaces more smoothly.
It can interfere with art direction.